# How to get work JavaScript requestFullscren on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, fullscreen

I have a function for fullscreen mode. It wark in all browsers and android devices, except iOS.

How can I enter fullscreen mode in iOS device browsers?

```
var toggleFullScreen = function(mode) {
    if (mode) {
        var element = document.documentElement;
        if(element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
        } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if(document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
};
```